# Deploying microservices communicating through kafka

Tags: apache-kafka, microservices, devops

I have a system built of microservices communicating using Kafka. How should the topics be created during deployment?

I see two options:

I. Centralized topics creation. Have a central place (repository) where teams add the topics required by their microservices. In this approach, the deployment will look as follows:

```
 1. Deploy kafka
 2. Deploy kafka topics artifact that contains the required topics for all microservices
 3. Deploy microservices
```

II. Every service deploys its own topics. The deployment looks as follows:

```
 1. Deploy Kafka
 2. Deploy microservices. Within each microservice deployment the required topics are created.
```

I see the value in option I. I could see all the topics that are deployed, partitions, retention and compaction policies. This would help be understand kafka resource allocation and its configuration. The downside of this option is a potential coupling, where I would need to deploy a single microservice on a running system. In this scenario I would need to deploy a new version of Kafka topics artifact and the microservice itself.

What are the best practices here?

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I have seen both approaches, and it comes down to how well your approval processes work and if you really want to micro-manage server resource usage (quotas, access control, discoverability, etc).

For example - a team wants to make a Kafka POC and does not want to wait for "Kafka admin approval" to create topics, so they use `AdminClient` API in their code to get started quickly. Kafka Streams, however, **will** create intermediate stateful topics on its own, and so you cannot consistently create all the topics it needs ahead of time.

Other example - the Kafka team wants to audit and control how/when topics are used and how large they can be, so they setup tools like OpenPolicyAgent to control what can be defined in a central repo. They may also setup an admin UI panel to create/discover topics.

Then there is a middle ground - one repo per "team/organization" for topics.

Note: You can use Terraform, Kubernetes Operators, Ansible, etc for managing Kafka topics; doesn't have to be "typical" Kafka client tools. And if you use these tools, you're not really "deploying a topic artifact"; instead you can run these through a GitOps flow with Jenkins, Github Actions, etc.

Answer (score 0):

May be you can make an approach based on development environment. You can have no restriction in dev but fully managed in PROD and your testing env can be a mix.

From a real-world experience it wont matter how a topic is created but what really matters is the constraints enforced on top of it. Two key things are :

- ACL (Access Control List) for governance, especially if you are in a finance industry where the Risk team audits the entire process end to end and first question would be how your topic is secured and how do you make sure that none others can access your topic.
- Quota, to save server resources being overused by producers/consumers of a topic. Since Kafka cluster would be a shared env, someone can run a batch job and make the cluster throttled for others.

So in organisations where Kafka acts as a central nerve, mostly there would be an approval process from Kafka cluster maintainers for topic creation. They maintain a git repo and asks other teams to checkin the topic configurations and run some tool on top of it for topics. So it becomes a controlled env with a single point of source for all topics like who owns it and can check if the requested configurations are ok and can ask for explanation.

These all makes sense based on how widely the cluster going to be used. A simple scenario would be retention bytes/time. It's clearly based on use case. So an admin can ask requestors to reduce than the default one configured to save storage in cluster.